# How to delete a commit from a deleted unmerged branch?

Tags: git

[image]

- I accidentally created a branch with an incorrect name, and subsequently made a commit to it.

  - Lets call this: `commit #1` to `feature branch 'A'`.
- I copied the files included in `commit #1` to a temp folder.
- I deleted the `branch A` upon realising I'd incorrectly named it.
- I then created the branch (lets call this `feature branch B`) with the correct name and 'copy & pasted' in the prior work I'd put  in the temp folder, effectively recreating `commit #1`

  - Lets call this `commit #2` to `feature branch B`
- I continued with work, completed `feature branch B`, and then released to `develop` & `master`.

**How do I delete `commit #1` and `feature branch A` completely from git history and make it look like they never happened?**

### 2018-04-11

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--r), my "ghost" branch was a tracking branch.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you have deleted the branch? In your screenshot I can see both branch-name and commit.

Comment: Yes it is deleted. `git branch -v` confirms this

Comment: By the way, you can _rename_ Git branches: `git branch -m <oldbranch> <newbranch>`

Comment: Try `git branch -va`. If you still don't see it then you are either looking at a different repo in that GUI, or the GUI has cached something.

Comment: `git branch -va` indeed shows the deleted branch name

Comment: And what do you see when you run `git branch -D branch`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete remote branch you need to run:

```
git push --delete origin your-remote-branch-name
```

to delete local branch, you need to run:

```
git branch -d your-local-branch
```

if this gives an error saying it is not fully merged, then use:

```
git branch -D your-local-branch
```

Don't worry about the commit, you should not be deleting commits from git. Also, you should have just created a branch on that commit with a correct name and deleted branch with an old name instead of copying the work and recreating a branch

Comment: completeness never hurt nobody :)

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -rd <name of ghost branch>`

---

- `git branch -v` did not show the old branch (i.e. it looked deleted)
- `git branch -va` showed the branch was still referenced
- `git branch -d <name of ghost branch>` did **not** work
- `git branch -rd`  **did** work

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), it means your “ghost” branch was a tracking one. You did not mention it in the question, please include it to make the question self-contained.